# Ive an iPhone 5(GSM) Running on ios 7.0.3 i cant restore the itunes says that the IPSW is not compatible?

Tags: iphone, restore

[image]

I've an iPhone 5(GSM) running on ios 7.0.3. I can't restore. iTunes says that the IPSW is not compatible?

Comment: Apple stops authenticating/signing obsolete iOS builds for devices that are capable of running the newest build. If your device still works you could try erasing  all content and settings from the device. If it truly needs a restore you may have to jailbreak it or upgrade to iOS 8.